# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka add headers to only one binding

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

The reference manual for Spring Cloud Stream says that you can use the property "spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers" to set the headers for all bindings. Is there a way to set the headers for a specific binding? For example, something like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    input:
      destination: input-topic
      headers: header-for-input-only
    output:
      destination: input-topic
      headers: header-for-output-only
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, it's a binder-wide setting. More granular settings could be a new feature.

Comment: Definitely something that would be useful, if you guys have time. Currently it seems to produce a weird EOF exception if it's expecting the headers and doesn't get them.

Comment: Please file an issue with the description - it helps to have input from the community! (and contributions fwiw)

Comment: Good point. I'll try to remember to do so next time I have my GitHub password handy. :-) Thanks!